# DDD Multi-stage user creation

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm converting some old MVC/Service code to CQRS/DDD.

To create a user, I need to:

1. call an external service to create an account in that system, and retrieve the guid associated with that new external account.
2. create my local user domain object (which requires the externally created guid) - and store it in the local database.  *The 2 systems are entirely separate and the only shared data is the user guid.*

I also want to bulk create users.
If some part of the user creation fails, I need to undo the external user creation.

Trying to keep within true DDD how can I do this?

Option 1 - Attach a handler to the 'user created' event, and make the call to the external service to retrieve the guid, and set the value, but then my user domain has been created in an invalid state (there must be a guid).

Option 2 - Call the external service as part of my 'Create user' handler, and then create the user domain. I would also have to duplicate this code in the 'Bulk create users' handler.

Are there other options?

I thought about using Sagas, but this seems heavy handed.

Comment: Your question misses a lot of important context. For example, what "creation of a user" means. Is this the construction of a user object just for your service, temporarily "in memory", for a restricted number of user objects of a certain use case? Or as records in some database, with the idea of synching the set of all users in full with the account of the external service? By "user domain", you mean "user object in your domain model", I guess? Please try to edit your question and invest a little bit more time in clarity. Keep in mind we don't know your system. Thanks.

Comment: Is this GUID used by anything else? Because a failure that requires a delete requires it everywhere the GUID went.

Comment: Is the right service creating the GUID?  Its not a good setup if two services both have to agree it should exist.

Comment: Why do you need to create the external GUID prior to confirming the user is valid?

Comment: @candied_orange The first service creates the GUID, the 2nd one just uses it for reference.

Comment: @candied_orange The external service provides account creation/management/password services.  My service only needs to keep data relevant to itself, but it links to the external service via the GUID.

Comment: @neil you said that already. Doesn’t answer my questions. How many things care about the GUID? How many might reject creation?

Comment: @candied_orange I think you are getting hung up on the wrong part of the problem.  I have 2 systems that need to be kept in sync during account creation. How do I do this within a DDD setting?

Comment: @neil I’ll try asking again. Do you have two systems that can both independently reject account creation?

Comment: @candied_orange Yes, the external system can reject/fail account creation, which means the internal system will not create an account.  Alternately, the external system can succeed, and the internal system can then fail, in which case the external system will need to be told to delete its new account.  I can't modify the external system.

Comment: @neil ok so if the external system rejects user creation, and you haven’t created an internal user yet, what do you do next?

Comment: If either system can't create an account I return an error to the caller to say the account wasn't created.